# Cannot get access_token from oauth2-example-orion-client

Tags: oauth, fiware-orion, fiware

I'm using oauth2-example-orion-client from https://github.com/fgalan/oauth2-example-orion-client/ , and I followed the steps, however after log in with my filab account (I´ve already created an application to get the Oauth credentials), I get the following error when it the to go to 'callback_uri'/login:

```
express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env') in an if statement server.js:16:5
Server listen in port 80. Connect to localhost
127.0.0.2 - - [Tue, 05 Aug 2014 20:43:22 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 342 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20131029 Firefox/17.0"
/home/nmerino/Desktop/oauth2sample/server.js:85
        req.session.oauth_token = results.access_token;
                                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined
    at /home/nmerino/Desktop/oauth2sample/server.js:85:42
    at /home/nmerino/Desktop/oauth2sample/oauth2.js:138:18
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/nmerino/Desktop/oauth2sample/oauth2.js:115:5)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1487:9)
    at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1302:19)
    at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:896:10)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:430:15)
```

Althought the message make seem I´m using localhost, I´m using 127.0.0.2 instead, to run the oauth.
Please I need help with these errors.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the access token using the token_script.sh script, as described in the [Orion quick start guide](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Quick_Start_for_Programmers).